# How google API verifies a usage by specific bundleID (apple) or andorid app?

Tags: api

i'm reading about how google restricts the usage of the API keys.
they have 2 options - by bundle ID and by application's SHA-1 fingerprint.

I'm guessing that this info is sent along the request from the app itself to Google - what denies me from taking this key, and forging a request using that bundle ID for example?

My guess is that it's just another small wall the attacker should pass, and it stops the "common attackers", although it's not that hard to forge.

Am i correct?

Comment: Good question! Although you may want to be a little bit more specific about the Google Service you are talking about.

Comment: It doesn't matter, let's say Google Maps